# how to find different parts of speech for same word using nltk?

Tags: python

I have created a list of words for the given text using NLTK. According to english text, a word can be of different parts of speech

Example:
The heavens are above. (Adverb)

The moral code of conduct is above the civil code of conduct. (Preposition)

Read the sentence given above. (Adjective)

Our blessings come from above. (Noun)

when i give above as input my program as to give Adverb, preposition adjective and noun 
i want to find differnet POS  tagging for same word.